# Visual Studio Editor: Remove Structured IF/End If

Tags: visual-studio, editor

Is there and easy way to remove the **IF/End If** structured pairing.
Being able to do this in one keystroke would be nice (I also use Refactor! Pro)

Right now this is what I do:

1. Delete the **IF** line
2. Watch Visual Studio reformat the code to line up correctly taking into account that the **IF** is Missing.
3. Navigate to the **End If**
4. Delete the **End If** line

i.e. In the following example I want to change the code from

```
IF Value = True Then
  DoSomething()
  DoSomething2()
End IF
```

To

```
DoSomething()
DoSomething2()
```

Comment: That's not a re-factor, since it changes the meaning of the code.  Refactoring should result in code that exhibits the same behavior as the previous version.  This is more along the lines of debugging or new code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the question and removed references to Refactor.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not a literal refactoring in the sense specified by Martin Fowler's book [Refactoring](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#refactoring), This is how I use resharper to achieve this goal:

1. Move/click on like with **if** statement
2. Press **control + delete** to delete the line
3. Press **Alt + enter**, and the option *remove braces* will be the first one specified.
4. Press **enter**

Done. Not quite simple, but the keystrokes are short, and not too complicated, and I don't have to spend/waste time with dumb arrow keys or the mouse to accomplish this type of code change.

Resharper supports VB.net code as of 4.0, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am going to have to see if Refactor! Pro has a similar feature. I also edited the question and removed references to Refactor.